# Create a matrix from three column vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have three column vectors, then I want to creat matrix from this column victors
    A1(:);
    A2(:);
    A3(:)

each column vectors has  25 element then the new matrix C will be a matrix with 3x25

```
I want to make A1(:) the first column of matrix c
A2(:)   second column
A3(:)   third column
```

Comment: If you want to get an output, C of size `3x25`, you would have the first row of C as `A1` and not the column. If not, could you clarify on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`cat`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cat)** to concatenate along dimension `1` or `2` depending on how you input those three vectors.

Thus, you can use -

```
C = cat(2,A1(:),A2(:),A3(:)).'
```

Or

```
C = cat(1,A1(:).',A2(:).',A3(:).')
```

Of course, you can skip `(:)`'s, if you know that all those are column vectors.

The above two approaches assumes that you intend to get an output of size `3 x N`, where is `N` is the number of elements in the column vectors. If you were looking to get an output of size `N x 3` , i.e. where each column is formed from the elements of column vectors `A1`, `A2` and so on, just drop the transpose from the first of the two approaches mentioned above. Thus, use this -

```
C = cat(2,A1(:),A2(:),A3(:))
```

Comment: +1 specially for not introducing an unwanted complex conjugate! :-)